# ASP.NET Identity PasswordHasher producing different hashes on each request

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm running into a peculiar issue with a solution I'm working on. It uses the ASP.NET Identity system with a custom implementation that I built to work with my existing data. Up until yesterday, it worked fine, but then somehow I couldn't log in anymore. From what I can tell, it looks like the password hasher is producing different hashes on each request, non of which match the hash that's stored in the database.

Is there something I'm doing wrong that makes this happen? Not sure if this matters, but I'm working on a local copy of the solution I downloaded from my office computer because RDP was becoming annoying. It did work locally at one point, but I think it stopped when I changed my database seeding from object based to a straight SQL script. Not sure why that would make it not work considering I was inserting the same values, but here I am, unable to authenticate.

**UPDATE**

The `UserManager` I'm using is passed in an instance of my `UserStore` via Ninject. Here's the code for my `UserStore`:

```
public class EmployeeStore : IQueryableUserStore<Employee, int>, IUserStore<Employee, int>, IUserPasswordStore<Employee, int>, IUserRoleStore<Employee, int>, IDisposable {
    private bool Disposed;
    private IDatabaseRepository<Role> RolesRepository { get; set; }
    private IDatabaseRepository<Employee> EmployeesRepository { get; set; }

    public EmployeeStore(
        IDatabaseRepository<Role> rolesRepository,
        IDatabaseRepository<Employee> employeesRepository) {
        this.RolesRepository = rolesRepository;
        this.EmployeesRepository = employeesRepository;
    }

    #region IQueryableUserStore Members
    public IQueryable<Employee> Users {
        get {
            return this.EmployeesRepository.Set;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region IUserStore Members
    public async Task CreateAsync(
        Employee employee) {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();

        if (employee == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("employee");
        }

        await this.EmployeesRepository.AddAndCommitAsync(employee);
    }

    public async Task DeleteAsync(
        Employee employee) {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();

        if (employee == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("employee");
        }

        await this.EmployeesRepository.RemoveAndCommitAsync(employee);
    }

    public Task<Employee> FindByIdAsync(
        int employeeId) {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();

        return Task.FromResult<Employee>(this.EmployeesRepository.FindSingleOrDefault(
            u =>
                (u.Id == employeeId)));
    }

    public Task<Employee> FindByNameAsync(
        string userName) {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();

        return Task.FromResult<Employee>(this.EmployeesRepository.FindSingleOrDefault(
            e =>
                (e.UserName == userName)));
    }

    public async Task UpdateAsync(
        Employee employee) {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();

        if (employee == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("employee");
        }

        await this.EmployeesRepository.CommitAsync();
    }
    #endregion

    #region IDisposable Members
    public void Dispose() {
        this.Dispose(true);

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected void Dispose(
        bool disposing) {
        this.Disposed = true;
    }

    private void ThrowIfDisposed() {
        if (this.Disposed) {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(base.GetType().Name);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region IUserPasswordStore Members
    public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(
        Employee employee) {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();

        if (employee == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("employee");
        }

        return Task.FromResult<string>(employee.PasswordHash);
    }

    public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(
        Employee employee) {
        return Task.FromResult<bool>(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.PasswordHash));
    }

    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(
        Employee employee,
        string passwordHash) {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();

        if (employee == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("employee");
        }

        employee.PasswordHash = passwordHash;

        return Task.FromResult<int>(0);
    }
    #endregion

    #region IUserRoleStore Members
    public Task AddToRoleAsync(
        Employee employee,
        string roleName) {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();

        if (employee == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("employee");
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(roleName)) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("roleName");
        }

        Role role = this.RolesRepository.FindSingleOrDefault(
            r =>
                (r.Name == roleName));

        if (role == null) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Role not found");
        }

        employee.Roles.Add(role);

        return Task.FromResult<int>(0);
    }

    public Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(
        Employee employee) {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();

        if (employee == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("employee");
        }

        return Task.FromResult<IList<string>>(employee.Roles.Select(
            r =>
                r.Name).ToList());
    }

    public Task<bool> IsInRoleAsync(
        Employee employee,
        string roleName) {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();

        if (employee == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("employee");
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(roleName)) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("roleName");
        }

        return Task.FromResult<bool>(employee.Roles.Any(
            r =>
                (r.Name == roleName)));
    }

    public Task RemoveFromRoleAsync(
        Employee employee,
        string roleName) {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();

        if (employee == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("employee");
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(roleName)) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("roleName");
        }

        Role role = this.RolesRepository.FindSingleOrDefault(
            r =>
                (r.Name == roleName));

        if (role == null) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Role is null");
        }

        employee.Roles.Remove(role);

        return Task.FromResult<int>(0);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And here's my login controller:

```
public sealed class SiteController : BaseController {
    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager {
        get {
            return this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }

    private UserManager<Employee, int> EmployeeManager { get; set; }

    public SiteController(
        UserManager<Employee, int> employeeManager) {
        this.EmployeeManager = employeeManager;
    }

    [HttpGet, AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Default() {
        return base.View();
    }

    [HttpPost, AllowAnonymous, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<RedirectToRouteResult> Default(
        [Bind(Prefix = "Credentials", Include = "Email,Password")] Credentials credentials) {
        if (this.ModelState.IsValid) {
            Employee employee = await EmployeeManager.FindAsync(credentials.Email, credentials.Password);

            if (employee != null) {
                ClaimsIdentity identityClaim = await this.EmployeeManager.CreateIdentityAsync(employee, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

                if (identityClaim != null) {
                    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties(), identityClaim);

                    return base.RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
                }
            }
        }

        return base.RedirectToAction("Default");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public RedirectToRouteResult SignOut() {
        this.AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        return base.RedirectToAction("Default");
    }
}
```

As far as the machine key, yes, it did change when I copied the solution to my home computer. That being said, I took it from one Windows 7 machine to another Windows 7 machine, and I never specified the machine key in any config file, so it should behave identically on both machines. As far as the salt, I don't think I'm setting that anywhere. I've only had the ASP.NET Identity implementation up for three or four days, so it's probably incomplete somehow.

Comment: Any chance it has something to do with your machine key setting in your web.config?  Maybe something different between your work environment and your home environment.

Comment: Hard to tell what's going wrong without seeing some code. You may want to check that any salt you're using to generate the hash is correct.

Comment: I've updated my post with the code I'm using.

Comment: Alex, I think Tim is spot on with his comment about the machine key.  The reason you specify the machine key in the config file, is so that when you move between computers, it uses the same key to encrypt/decrypt the data.  If that key changes when running the code on different computers (think separate web servers in a web farm), then you run into issues. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations  Try running from the original machine where it was running successfully, do you get the error there?

Comment: @BateTech, I read through the article and decided to follow their example and generate my own keys. So, I made a 128-bit SHA1 validation key,and a 64-bit AES decryption key. I then used the code from this guy: http://aspnetresources.com/blog/how_to_read_auto_generated_machinekey; to check and see what keys were really used. They were the ones I specified. Having done all that, the hasher is still producing different hashes on each request. I copied the project back to my work computer, and it did the same there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this turned out to be really stupid. The issue was being caused by Entity Framework not being aware of the records being inserted because I opted to execute a SQL script in the database initializer because I had a lot of statements and didn't want to write the object initialization equivalent. Turns out that even if the right data is in there, since EF didn't create and cache the objects, it simply returned nulls the whole time. It didn't even try to go out to the DB and check if the data was there.

So, lesson learned: don't use `ExecuteSqlCommand` to seed data into the database on the initializer. Wasted a whole day on this, I'm ecstatic!